# A Flag inside main function

Tags: java

Can I define a flag into my Main Function but not as static?
Here is my Code for the Main Function , and I want to use the Flag in a different class (Panel2 class)

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame 
{
    private Panel1 P1 = new Panel1();
    private Panel2 P2 = new Panel2();

    public static boolean flag = true;

    public MyFrame()
    {
        super("MyFrame");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(P1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(P2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyFrame mF=new MyFrame();
        mF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you can. just create instance of `MyFrame` inside `main` method and proceed from there.

Comment: The question in unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a local variable, then no - you can't declare a local variable in one method and then use it in another method, even within the same class. It only "exists" as far as the method it's declared in is concerned. You can pass the value of a local variable into a method or constructor called within the declaring method, of course:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int someValue = 10;
    myMethod(someValue);
}

private static void myMethod(int parameter) {
    System.out.println("I was passed " + parameter);
}
```

... but that's not really the same thing.

Note that instance and static variables should generally be private anyway - access to them should basically be through the methods in the class.

If you're just starting to get to grips with object orientation, I'd suggest writing *console* apps to get the hang of things; GUIs present their own challenges, and it's easier to start with something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of how you will be using the flag variable, in your code sample I did not see the flag used at all, I don't see why you would prefer to avoid using a static variable in your case, but if that is something crucial, one of the solution would be to use the flag variable as a public variable (none static variable) of the MyFrame Class and then access to it from your main function :

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame 
{
private Panel1 ;
private Panel2 ;       
public  boolean flag;

    public MyFrame()
    {
        super("MyFrame");
        this.flag = true;
        P1 = new Panel1();
        P2 = new Panel2();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(P1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(P2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        setSize(500,400);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyFrame mF=new MyFrame();

     // you can access your flag this way 
     mF.flag = false; // or use it the way you want !
     mF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    }
```

But if you want to use that flag inside of the Panel2 class then you will probably need to add a new constructor to your Panel2 class that accepts JFrame type as a parameter which you will pass as instance to it...

```
  public class MyFrame extends JFrame 
    {
    private Panel1 ;
    private Panel2 ;       
    public  boolean flag;

        public MyFrame()
        {
            super("MyFrame");
            P1 = new Panel1();
            this.flag = true;
            P2 = new Panel2(this); /* then you will be able to have a visibility 
    on the flag variable of your MyFrame instance.*/

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(P1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(P2,BorderLayout.EAST);
            setSize(500,400);
            setVisible(true);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyFrame mF=new MyFrame();

         // you can access your flag this way 
         mF.flag = false; // or use it the way you want !
         mF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

        }
```

You can also add functions to Panel2 that accepts a boolean variable in which you can pass the flag variable while you are in your main function

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do

```
static boolean flag=true
```

you can do

```
boolean flag=true
```

but then in your main you'd need to access it using

```
mF.flag
```

Is this what you are trying to do? The question is a bit unclear. Can you rephrase it?